# Is it possible to replace a Data Extract file in an exported ZIP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio, tracking-extract, zip

Creating a Tracking extract, but there are errors in the NOT SENT file.  We have created a process to remove the bad data and create a new "NOTSENT.CSV" file, but is it possible to put this file into an existing .ZIP on the SFTP folder?

Basically, we want to replace the Not Sent file that is auto-generated and placed in a ZIP with our edited Not Sent file and overwrite the original file in the ZIP.

Perhaps with SSJS?  other ideas?  THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

You can extract and import Not Sent tracking data into a Not Sent Data Extension and do whatever you please with it.  It's convoluted, but it should give you the flexibility to launder the data before the final extract.

Automation Steps:

1. Tracking Extract
2. File Transfer from Safehouse
3. File Transfer Unzip
4. Import NotSent.csv
5. Data Extension Extract

Alternatively, there is a NotSent SOAP object from which you can retrieve data in a Script Activity using WSProxy, but it doesn't include the Reason (making it useless, IMO).

Comment: We actually did just as you suggest, but the real issue is that I want to place the file into the ZIP file... alternatively, replace the original file in the ZIP with the "new" version of NotSent.

Comment: I'm suggesting creating a new zip file. I don't think you can modify one that's already existing -- only unzip it.

Comment: that was my worry.  Thank you for the feedback